# Python: importing another .py file

Tags: python, import, function

I have a class and I want to import a def function by doing:

```
import <file>
```

but when I try to call it, it says that the def can not be found. I also tried:

```
from <file> import <def>
```

but then it says global name 'x' is not defined.

So how can I do this?

Edit:

Here is a example of what I am trying to do. In file1.py I have:

```
var = "hi"

class a:
  def __init__(self):
    self.b()

  import file2

a()
```

and in file2.py I have:

```
def b(self):
  print(var)
```

it is just giving me a error though.

Comment: what are you trying to import, is it built in? and if not is it in the same directory as your working directory?

Comment: You don't import a `file`; you import a *module*, or names contained in a module. `import modulename`, not `import filename.py`. You'll need to add a more concrete example to illustrate your problem better.

Comment: Can you put the actual import statement and the actual absolute file paths in your post?

Comment: ...huh. I never thought of importing a class's methods from another module. It actually works, once you fix the syntax. I'm not sure whether it'd ever be a good idea, though.

Comment: huh... Well what is wrong with the syntax?

Comment: Whats your actual error message?

Answer (score 7):

```
import file2
```

loads the module `file2` and binds it to the name `file2` in the current namespace. `b` from `file2` is available as `file2.b`, not `b`, so it isn't recognized as a method. You could fix it with

```
from file2 import b
```

which would load the module and assign the `b` function from that module to the name `b`. I wouldn't recommend it, though. Import `file2` at top level and define a method that delegates to `file2.b`, or define a mixin superclass you can inherit from if you frequently need to use the same methods in unrelated classes. Importing a function to use it as a method is confusing, and it breaks if the function you're trying to use is implemented in C.